# Format a DataGridDateTimeColumn in wpf datagrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am working on a datagrid and binding it in code behind file where I supply datatable default view to the datagrid. The datagrid contains a DataGridDateTimeColumn which is bound successfully.

I need to show this DataGridDateTimeColumn each 1st to 9th row with both **date and time value** while rest of the time (each 10th row) only **time value**. the problem is even I am passing only time value to the 10th row then also it takes system date appended with time (time which I gave). I don't know what is the wrong here.

```
<c1:C1DataGrid ScrollMode="Deferred" Name="TabulerDataGrid" Visibility="Hidden"></c1:C1DataGrid>
```

Here is C# code:

```
private void BindDataGrid(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataColumn col in dataCollection.Columns)
        {
            if (col.ColumnName == "Time")
            {
                C1.WPF.DataGrid.DataGridDateTimeColumn column = 
                    new C1.WPF.DataGrid.DataGridDateTimeColumn();

                column.Format = GlobalDataDisplay.DateFormat;  //TTP 6321
                column.FilterMemberPath = "OnlyDate";
                DataGridContentFilter f = new DataGridContentFilter();
                DataGridDateTimeFilter d = new DataGridDateTimeFilter();
                d.EditMode = C1DateTimePickerEditMode.DateTime;
                f.Content = d;
                column.Filter = f;
                column.CanUserFilter = true;
                column.Header = col.ColumnName;

               column.Binding = new System.Windows.Data.Binding {
                         Path = new PropertyPath(col.ColumnName), 
                    Converter = new ConvertDateChange()};

                TabulerDataGrid.Columns.Add(column);
            }
      }   
        TabulerDataGrid.ItemsSource = dataCollection.DefaultView; 

// time value is extracted from datacollection and provided to column.
foreach (C1.WPF.DataGrid.DataGridRow row in this.TabulerDataGrid.Rows.Where(x => x.Index % 10 == 0))
            {
               if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dateTime))
                {
                    DateTime dt = (DateTime)(row.DataItem as DataRowView)[0];
                    (row.DataItem as DataRowView)[0] = dt.ToString("HH:mm:ss");; 
                }
            }

}
```

Comment: describe `c1:C1DataGrid`

Comment: @safi - c1:C1DataGrid is a component one datagrid.

Comment: i mean put `c1:C1DataGrid` Template

Comment: @safi : actually I am binding it in the code behind file.Please check the updated code.

Comment: the problem that i figured out is in your `C1.WPF.DataGrid.DataGridDateTimeColumn` you send string and it convert it by `StringFormat` i suppose using `DataGridTextColumn` or if you want to put TimeControl you can use `DataGridTemplateColumn`

Comment: I tried earlier with DataGridTextColumn but it was having same issue.

Comment: actually we don't reach each other, I need more details about your problem